# Does Justin Bieber - Love Yourself have sexual meaing?

Tags: meaning

I have a simple question.
When Justin sings "go and love yourself" does this have sexual meaning?

Comment: I'm not familiar with his work. Could it be a euphemism for f*** off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an euphemism for "Go and f**k yourself". Here's some info from Ed Sheeran who wrote the song:

“Originally, I was like hearing Rihanna kind of coming in with a bit of that swag,” Ed told Howard, explaining that the song’s original chorus was, “Baby, you should go and fuck yourself” rather than “Baby, you should go and love yourself.”

https://www.howardstern.com/news/2017/3/7/ed-sheeran-reveals-original-nsfw-love-yourself-lyric-he-wrote-rihanna-not-justin-bieber/

Comment: Thank you. I understood your answer as "Yes".